# What program can plot a parametric equation with 3 or more time parameters?

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d, parametric

I'd like to make projections of this equation:

$$x(u,v) = (r\cos(u)+R_1)\cos(v)$$
$$y(u,v) = (r\cos(u)+R_1)\sin(v)$$
$$z(t,u) = (r\sin(u)+R_2)\cos(t)$$
$$w(t,u) = (r\sin(u)+R_2)\sin(t)$$

where,

$$0 < t < 2 \pi$$
$$0 < u < 2 \pi$$
$$0 < v < 2 \pi$$

and,

$$ R_1  >,<,=  R_2 > r $$

Which is a really cool four dimensional torus, seen in slices, here:

[Rotating slice at origin](https://i.imgur.com/3WwPkBE.gif)

[Passing through a 3-plane at various angles](https://i.imgur.com/j7LWsnP.gif)

Unfortunately, the program I've been using only accepts 2 time parameters. Unless there's a way to 'consolidate' a 3-parameter equation into 2 (without loss of info about the shape), then I'm looking for another program. Any good suggestions?

Comment: What is the program you are currently using?

Comment: Calcplot3D, right now. That's how I made the two animations.

Comment: Have you looked into Mathematica? It's expensive and there's a little learning curve, but I think it should be able to handle what you need.

Comment: I have. Looks like a great program. I have many uses for it, actually. Projecting 3 time variables would create a 3D mesh of curved, cubic cells, that tile 3D space. I haven't seen a program or any examples of this, other than here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkaI6meNiI0 , which is the shape I detailed above. I can't contact the creator, though.